# Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8080/manager/text/list

Tags: java, jenkins, tomcat9

I have been trying to build successfully in jenkins since yesterday but its not building.
I have tried starting up tomcat server several times but it still does not build. I even tried reinstalling tomcat server.
I have started my tomcat server in eclipse too.
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

tomcat-users.xml

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="password" roles="manager-script, manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I did that because the console output is very very long. Sorry about that.

Comment: You need to fix your question and get rid of the images.  For a start, unless people have very good eyesight (or a very large screen) those screenshots are unreadable.  Q: Why is answering your question? A: Partly because they can't read it, partly because it is breaking the rules, ...